# React js Carousel Arrows / position

Tags: css, reactjs

Hello I have difficulty putting my arrows in the center and one on the left and one on the right of my carousel
could someone help me with this?

now i have this
[image]

my code:

```
  <Visibility
                onBottomPassed={()=>stickTopMenu()}
                onBottomVisible={()=> unStickTopMenu()}
                once={false}
          > 
        <Grid style={{backgroundColor:'#000',paddingTop:0}}>
        <Grid.Row columns={1} style={{padding:0}}>
          <Grid.Column style={{padding:0}}>
          <ImageCarousel />
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid.Row>
        </Grid>
        </Visibility>
```

and:

```
const ImageCarousel = () => (
  <CarouselProvider
    totalSlides={3}
    naturalSlideWidth={1}
    naturalSlideHeight={1}
  >
    <Slider style={{ maxHeight: "500px"}}>
      <Slide  tag="a" index={0}>
        <Image   src="https://lorempixel.com/800/800/cats/0" />
      </Slide>
      <Slide tag="a" index={1}>
        <Image src="https://lorempixel.com/800/800/cats/1" />
      </Slide>
      <Slide tag="a" index={2}>
        <Image src="https://lorempixel.com/800/800/cats/2" />
      </Slide>
    </Slider>
    <ButtonBack style={{position: 'absolute', top:' 50%',left: 0,transform: 'translateY(-50%)'}}>Back</ButtonBack>
    <ButtonNext style={{position: 'absolute', top:' 50%',left: 0,transform: 'translateY(-50%)'}}>Next</ButtonNext>
  </CarouselProvider>
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should add a reference to the parent element. Also, remember you have to transform X and Y

```
const ImageCarousel = () => (
  <CarouselProvider
    totalSlides={3}
    naturalSlideWidth={1}
    naturalSlideHeight={1}
    style={{position: "relative" }}
  >
    <Slider style={{ maxHeight: "500px"}}>
      <Slide  tag="a" index={0}>
        <Image   src="https://lorempixel.com/800/800/cats/0" />
      </Slide>
      <Slide tag="a" index={1}>
        <Image src="https://lorempixel.com/800/800/cats/1" />
      </Slide>
      <Slide tag="a" index={2}>
        <Image src="https://lorempixel.com/800/800/cats/2" />
      </Slide>
    </Slider>
    <ButtonBack style={{position: 'absolute', top:'50%',left: 20,transform: 'translate(-50%,-50%)'}}>Back</ButtonBack>
    <ButtonNext style={{position: 'absolute', top:'50%',right: 20,transform: 'translate(-50%,-50%)'}}>Next</ButtonNext>
  </CarouselProvider>
);
```

Comment: thanks a lot  
how could I center in a container this two button

Comment: No problem. So I am not sure what you mean by center in a container. Would be the CarouselProvider container? If yes, please increase the left and right values.

Comment: Basically I wanted to put a semantic container and position one in flex end and one in flex start

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59354652/react-js-carousel-and-positions if u can help me on this post