# react js carousel and positions

Tags: css, reactjs

Hello i have a carousel but i have a problem leaving the image 100% according to the size of my carousel

```
const ImageCarousel = () => (
  <CarouselProvider
  totalSlides={3}
  naturalSlideWidth={1}
  naturalSlideHeight={1.25}
  dragEnabled={false}
  touchEnabled={false}
  style={{ height: "500",position: "relative"}}
  >
    <Slider style={{maxHeight:'500px', width:'100%'}}>
      <Slide tag="a" index={0}>
        <Image  src="https://lorempixel.com/800/800/cats/0" />
      </Slide>
      <Slide tag="a" index={1}>
        <Image src="https://lorempixel.com/800/800/cats/1" />
      </Slide>
      <Slide tag="a" index={2}>
        <Image src="https://lorempixel.com/800/800/cats/2" />
      </Slide>
    </Slider>
    <Container style={{position: 'relative', backgroundColor:'#000'}}>
    <ButtonBack style={{position: 'absolute', transform: 'translate(-50%,-50%)', backgroundColor: 'transparent', border: 0}}><Icon fitted name='arrow right' size='big' /></ButtonBack>
    <ButtonNext style={{position: 'absolute', transform: 'translate(-50%,-50%)', backgroundColor: 'transparent', border: 0}}><Icon fitted name='arrow left' size='big' /></ButtonNext>
    </Container>
  </CarouselProvider>
);
```

now i have this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi This container should have a witdth.

1- Crate a css file called "ImageCarousel.css" in the same folder of ImageCarousel.js and place the code below:

```
.innterClass {
    height: 500px !important;
}
```

2- Import the code ImageCarousel.js

```
import "./ImageCarrousel.css";
```

3- Here is the code you should have in your ImageCarousel component:

```
const ImageCarousel = () => (
  <CarouselProvider
  totalSlides={3}
  naturalSlideWidth={1}
  naturalSlideHeight={1.25}
  dragEnabled={false}
  touchEnabled={false}
  style={{ height: "500",position: "relative"}}
  >
    <Slider style={{maxHeight:'500px'}}>
      <Slide innerClassName="innterClass" index={0}>
        <Image style={{objectFit: "cover"}}  src="https://lorempixel.com/800/800/cats/0" />
      </Slide>
      <Slide innerClassName="innterClass" index={1}>
        <Image style={{objectFit: "cover"}}  src="https://lorempixel.com/800/800/cats/1" />
      </Slide>
      <Slide innerClassName="innterClass" index={2}>
        <Image style={{objectFit: "cover"}}  src="https://lorempixel.com/800/800/cats/2" />
      </Slide>
    </Slider>
    <ButtonBack style={{position: 'absolute',top:'50%',left:'30%' ,transform: 'translate(-50%,-50%)', backgroundColor: 'transparent', border: 0}}><Icon fitted name='arrow right' size='big' /></ButtonBack>
    <ButtonNext style={{position: 'absolute', right:'30%', top: "50%", transform: 'translate(-50%,-50%)', backgroundColor: 'transparent', border: 0}}><Icon fitted name='arrow left' size='big' /></ButtonNext>

  </CarouselProvider>
);
```

Comment: Regarding the image I can not show it complete in my height could you give me a help?

Comment: Yes ... do you have it on github or you publish it on someplace where I can take a look?

Comment: yess : https://github.com/lostspirit1/carousel / my carousel on components / header and / assets / components / Carousel

Comment: Yes. You have to cut your image to work as a "banner" (half screen). Also, you could work with a div and set them as a background image. So you could use a properties called background-size and set it to cover. 
Also. Don't forget to put top: 50%; on your <ButtonNext component.

Comment: so i have to take my <image>

and add a div with an image

and use backgroundsize?

Comment: Please add my gasparteixeira to the repo then I can push the code I've change here.